# Creating Angular objects on the parent scope from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm building a simple form in Angular that allows the user to add or remove fields as they please. I've modeled this system off of an array of objects. When you begin the array is empty. When a row is added, and empty object should be pushed to the array on the parent scope. Pretty simple stuff. The controls for adding/removing rows is located on the directive itself.

http://plnkr.co/edit/niRdBvLNJyRQKg5RUC7e?p=preview

From what I understand, using either $eval or $parse is the key to adding a new object to my parent scope from the directive. I've been trying to use `$scope.addRow()` from the directive's controller but every time I use `$scope.$eval($attrs.ngModel)` within the function it returns undefined. Clearly, I'm not doing something right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot understood fully your question but if you want to pass binding object from parent to directive then do the following

```
 scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      rows: '=',
      title: '='
    },
```

If you  have to pass rows from parent to directive simply add in the scope and on the declaration of directive in html the object

http://plnkr.co/edit/kkkelHlwoHTfoUP1x8he?p=preview

Comment: holy crap I completely overthought that one. Long day. Thanks.